# ASPX page from subfolder in webforms project refresh content only after iisreset

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I have one subfolder '`mySubfolder`' in root of webforms project, 
in this folder I added one html page and one aspx page, test.html and test.aspx

when I access html and aspx page first time everything its ok, content of both page are loaded, but after few changes in html and in aspx page reload of aspx doesn't appear on page.

Changes from aspx page I can see only after `iisreset`

Some ideas why content from aspx page can't reloaded?

Comment: Do you have a code behind? Is this a Web Site Project or a Web Application Project?

Comment: @mason in code behind in page load I commented all code, in visual studio I opened webSite from local IIS, system operation is Windows Server

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio for this? When you created the project, did you create it via New Web Site or New Project?

Comment: @mason the project is not created by me, how i can to detect if is project or website?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? Do you see .designer.aspx.cs files?

Comment: @mason I use VS 2013, I see designer also source of design aspx, and code behind aspx.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, In Root web.config i have httpRuntime with attribute `fcnMode` with disable value, after set Default value all content from aspx page are refreshed